# FieldDoesNotExist on loading Fixture

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I'm trying to load a fixture called initial_data.json:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "logentry", "name": "log entry", "app_label": "admin"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "permission", "name": "permission", "app_label": "auth"}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "group", "name": "group", "app_label": "auth"}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "user", "name": "user", "app_label": "auth"}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "contenttype", "name": "content type", "app_label": "contenttypes"}}, {"pk": 6, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "session", "name": "session", "app_label": "sessions"}}, {"pk": 7, "model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "fields": {"model": "tweet", "name": "tweet", "app_label": "tweeter"}}, {"pk": "2pwa7lb5legwb02jw2h76f1e70j2jmo7", "model": "sessions.session", "fields": {"expire_date": "2014-09-14T00:20:41.773Z", "session_data": "OWQ4MmE3ZGRkZjliOWY3OTQ5OTdiMDIyYjE5ZWMwNmUwZTAyMThhMjp7Il9hdXRoX3VzZXJfYmFja2VuZCI6ImRqYW5nby5jb250cmliLmF1dGguYmFja2VuZHMuTW9kZWxCYWNrZW5kIiwiX2F1dGhfdXNlcl9pZCI6MX0="}}, {"pk": "ncl522f8kc6bf242chahmc2squtioirb", "model": "sessions.session", "fields": {"expire_date": "2014-09-14T01:19:42.407Z", "session_data": "NjY0NjliYjNkNDk0ODJhYWRjMDk5MjNjODA1NTAxYWIzZjg3ZGFkYzp7fQ=="}}, {"pk": 1, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_logentry", "name": "Can add log entry", "content_type": 1}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_logentry", "name": "Can change log entry", "content_type": 1}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_logentry", "name": "Can delete log entry", "content_type": 1}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_permission", "name": "Can add permission", "content_type": 2}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_permission", "name": "Can change permission", "content_type": 2}}, {"pk": 6, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_permission", "name": "Can delete permission", "content_type": 2}}, {"pk": 7, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_group", "name": "Can add group", "content_type": 3}}, {"pk": 8, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_group", "name": "Can change group", "content_type": 3}}, {"pk": 9, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_group", "name": "Can delete group", "content_type": 3}}, {"pk": 10, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_user", "name": "Can add user", "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 11, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_user", "name": "Can change user", "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 12, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_user", "name": "Can delete user", "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 13, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_contenttype", "name": "Can add content type", "content_type": 5}}, {"pk": 14, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_contenttype", "name": "Can change content type", "content_type": 5}}, {"pk": 15, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_contenttype", "name": "Can delete content type", "content_type": 5}}, {"pk": 16, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_session", "name": "Can add session", "content_type": 6}}, {"pk": 17, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_session", "name": "Can change session", "content_type": 6}}, {"pk": 18, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_session", "name": "Can delete session", "content_type": 6}}, {"pk": 19, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "add_tweet", "name": "Can add tweet", "content_type": 7}}, {"pk": 20, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "change_tweet", "name": "Can change tweet", "content_type": 7}}, {"pk": 21, "model": "auth.permission", "fields": {"codename": "delete_tweet", "name": "Can delete tweet", "content_type": 7}}, {"pk": 1, "model": "auth.user", "fields": {"username": "nina", "first_name": "", "last_name": "", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": true, "is_staff": true, "last_login": "2014-08-31T00:20:41.771Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$2LSBfxYO9fJJ$UT/BLyRLwBQIOUtOfA2aKkGw+xe44ZNYD2TWXqXoT3E=", "email": "", "date_joined": "2014-08-30T18:10:53.539Z"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "auth.user", "fields": {"username": "admin", "first_name": "Admin", "last_name": "", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": true, "is_staff": true, "last_login": "2014-08-31T00:22:38Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$6JY3bvlplRf0$Rm6rcK9M3LNuTw1uZ3B/Je7rq420UCaf2iwmY8pIv2U=", "email": "admin@admin.com", "date_joined": "2014-08-31T00:22:38Z"}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "auth.user", "fields": {"username": "bob", "first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Bobman", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": false, "is_staff": false, "last_login": "2014-08-31T00:23:06Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$ehuPT7BoKVpF$VZTxDeaHtLG7jU4wQ1erlFciwMk7l8aCp9MIjSVa/NU=", "email": "bob@bob.com", "date_joined": "2014-08-31T00:23:06Z"}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "auth.user", "fields": {"username": "amy", "first_name": "Amy", "last_name": "Smith", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": false, "is_staff": false, "last_login": "2014-08-31T00:23:24Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$Tv4vWeWICkfS$qcMP+xddceQZMVjHbdOhOsV6LKOQntKOkiaqdEzS2p8=", "email": "amy@smith.com", "date_joined": "2014-08-31T00:23:24Z"}}, {"pk": 1, "model": "tweeter.tweet", "fields": {"text": "I'm an Admin! ", "user": 2, "timestamp": "2014-08-30T18:51:04Z"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "tweeter.tweet", "fields": {"text": "Bob is the coolest name EVAR", "user": 3, "timestamp": "2014-08-29T18:51:19Z"}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "tweeter.tweet", "fields": {"text": "I <3 Tweeter", "user": 4, "timestamp": "2014-08-30T15:52:09Z"}}, {"pk": 1, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 1, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:22:38.417Z", "object_repr": "Admin", "object_id": "2", "change_message": "", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 2, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:22:57.048Z", "object_repr": "Admin", "object_id": "2", "change_message": "Changed first_name, email, is_staff and is_superuser.", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 1, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:23:06.858Z", "object_repr": "Bob", "object_id": "3", "change_message": "", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 2, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:23:17.098Z", "object_repr": "Bob", "object_id": "3", "change_message": "Changed first_name, last_name and email.", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 1, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:23:24.481Z", "object_repr": "Amy", "object_id": "4", "change_message": "", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 6, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 2, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:23:35.860Z", "object_repr": "Amy", "object_id": "4", "change_message": "Changed first_name, last_name and email.", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 7, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 1, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:51:05.451Z", "object_repr": "I'm an Admin! ", "object_id": "1", "change_message": "", "user": 1, "content_type": 7}}, {"pk": 8, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 1, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:51:26.097Z", "object_repr": "Bob is the coolest name EVAR", "object_id": "2", "change_message": "", "user": 1, "content_type": 7}}, {"pk": 9, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 1, "action_time": "2014-08-31T00:52:12.916Z", "object_repr": "I <3 Tweeter", "object_id": "3", "change_message": "", "user": 1, "content_type": 7}}, {"pk": 10, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 2, "action_time": "2014-08-31T01:06:18.846Z", "object_repr": "admin", "object_id": "2", "change_message": "Changed username.", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 11, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 2, "action_time": "2014-08-31T01:06:26.076Z", "object_repr": "bob", "object_id": "3", "change_message": "Changed username.", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}, {"pk": 12, "model": "admin.logentry", "fields": {"action_flag": 2, "action_time": "2014-08-31T01:06:34.096Z", "object_repr": "amy", "object_id": "4", "change_message": "Changed username.", "user": 1, "content_type": 4}}]
```

But I get the following error when I'm running `syncdb` or using `load data`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 364, in sync_apps
    hide_empty=True,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 90, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 141, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 84, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 78, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 120, in Deserializer
    field = Model._meta.get_field(field_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 554, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist('%s has no field named %r' % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/wrb473/Documents/workspace/angulardjango/tweeter/fixtures/initial_data.json': ContentType has no field named u'name'
```

Where is the problem with the fixture?

Comment: When asking it's important to strip the problem to its bare essentials. "[mcve]" says we need the smallest code and input data necessary to duplicate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes space and our time by forcing us to wade through worthless information, which results in slower answers to you, so help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType

"Changed in Django 1.8:
Before Django 1.8, the name property was a real field on the ContentType model." -- implies that as of 1.8 it's not a real field. Are you using 1.8? And if you remove name from your ContentType fixtures does it work?

Comment: removing name from ContentType worked. Thanks Megan!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `ContentType.name` is a property and not a `Field`.

An excerpt from `ContentType` model definition:

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
    objects = ContentTypeManager()

    # ...

    @property
    def name(self):
    # ...
```

The only fields defined on this model are `app_label` and `model`.
This means that code that serialized your objects has also included the property, whose value cannot be set when deserializing.

You can try removing anything that is not a model `Field` (in your case it is only `name`) from data on serialization.